# ClickOnce deployment stalls at the same point repeatedly for a single user

Tags: clickonce

I'm looking to expand my troubleshooting list for the situation where a single user (or sometimes an office) has a ClickOnce deployment repeatedly stall on the same file.  Items on my list so far in the first answer.

I've got a particular problem in mind with a customer who seems to be having a problem not caused by the first item on my list below.  I'll add a specific error message to the question when it becomes available.

Comment: For completeness, I'll note that there was no end to this story that we received; this was occurring when the user connected via AT&T DSL, and she resolved the issue with them.  I suspect there really was a proxy server in the mix down the line.

Answer (score 0):

The top reason tends to be a proxy server intervening and caching a partial download (due to, say a dropped connection).  When this happens, it will generally affect an entire office; the fix is to have the IT group set proxy server rules to either disable caching for the ClickOnce update website or to let connections to that site bypass the proxy server altogether.

Normally, that's where we can stop -- but the question is being motivated by a customer who doesn't appear to have a proxy server in the mix.  Other ideas:

- Bad download trapped in the browser cache.
- Disk is nearly full.

Answer (score 0):

My personal experience of this is at home, where I have content filtering set up on my firewall (DansGuardian). So rather than getting the expected application download the client PC gets the "This was blocked" web page content.

Adding the web site to the exception list solves this problem for me.

Comment: Not really the problem we were facing, though; the user could start a download, so the website wasn't blocked.

Answer (score 0):

As an aside, I've seen MTU mismatches cause [blackholes](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314825) that create wierd intermittent problems.   If a file is just the right size it won't download while other files transfer.  You might have seen something like this.